# How to understand the IO output from vmstat?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmstat

I use `vmstat` to get IO stats from ubuntu linux. Below is the description of this command:

```
IO
       bi: Blocks received from a block device (blocks/s).
       bo: Blocks sent to a block device (blocks/s).
```

I wonder what the `block device` means. Does it mean the local disk? I tried to copy a large file on my disk but this value didn't change.

Comment: Yes, local disk would be type of block device, but any device that stores data in blocks of certain size ( usually 512 Mb ) can be called block device. As for `vmstat` read the IO description again: received **from** block device.  `vmstat` is about memory, so it shows data copied **from** block dev to memory. Look for example at `mmap()`syscall. That maps a file on disk to RAM or virtual memory in general, because performance is better that way

Comment: You might try `iostat` to get I/O stats.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Your local disk should be a block device, and file copies should show in `bi` / `bo`.  They are displayed in units of kilobytes per second.

**USAGE NOTE**.  According to [`man vmstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/vmstat.8.html), the first line of `vmstat` numbers "gives averages since the last reboot".  And this is the *only* line shown if you run the command `vmstat`, without any options.  Subsequent lines give "information on a sampling period of length *delay*".  *delay* is an optional argument to `vmstat`.

Additionally, note that `vmstat` shows when data is written out to disk.  If you write a relatively small amount of data to a file, and your program does not explicitly flush it to disk, then it may stay in cache for some time and not be written to disk immediately.

The following example runs `vmstat 1` for a few seconds, while copying from `/dev/zero` to a file on my disk.  I use `sync` to make sure I see some disk writes.

```
$ mkdir test &&
   (cd test &&
    (sync ; vmstat 1 > vmstat.log & PID1=$! ; \
     cat </dev/zero >test & PID2=$! ; \
     sleep 3 ; kill $PID2 ; sync ; kill $PID1 ; \
     cat vmstat.log))

procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0 478976 2374288  76996 1023860    1    8    64   353   96  251 12  4 82  2  0
 0  2 478976 1782068  76996 1615824    0    0     0 202764 1405  786  0  9 56 34  0
 0  2 478976 1637036  76996 1760512    0    0     0 194572 1421 1013  0  2 59 39  0
 0  2 478976 1491580  76996 1906852    0    0     0 159760 1355  850  0  2 62 36  0
 0  1 478976 1491620  76996 1907068    0    0     0 129036  502  706  0  2 71 27  0
 1  1 478976 1491588  76996 1907068    0    0     0 157696  491  672  0  3 77 20  0
 0  3 478976 1491748  77004 1907064    0    0     0 19904  540 10719  0  2 73 25  0
```